# Configure LDAP certificate dir in PHP 5.5.x (Windows)

Tags: php, ldap, certificate, openldap, hardcoded

Until version 5.4, when PHP was compiled from its source, LDAP extension was hard coded to look for its certificates in **c:\openldap\sysconf** folder. Since 5.5, this 'harcode' was replace by an environment variable called %SYSCONFDIR%. However i can't make LDAP extension point to the same dir it did before, no matter what i do! :(

In PHP 5.4, ldap_config.h

```
#define LDAP_SYSCONFDIR "c:\\openldap\\sysconf"
```

In PHP 5.5, ldap_config.h

```
#define LDAP_SYSCONFDIR "%SYSCONFDIR%"
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version of PHP 5.5.

This has been resolved in the PHP 5.5.4 binaries from windows.php.net. The LDAP extension looks for "**c:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf**" as it had done in  5.4.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a trace with Sysinternals Process Explorer and it revealed that `php_ldap was` attempting to open the file `C:\Apache24\%SYSCONFDIR%\ldap.conf`, where `%SYSCONFDIR%` is interpreted literally and not expanded from the contents of an environment variable.
I have Apache installed in `C:\Apache24`, but obviously the exact path will vary depending on the name of your Apache folder.
In the root folder of your Apache installation, create a folder named `%SYSCONFDIR%` (literally!) and put `ldap.conf` in there. That solved it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately without an absolute location you will be left creating these folders in any directory where PHP may utilise LDAP as discussed here: http://unprotect-excel-sheet.com/phpldapfix.html

Comment: Even if i edit `ldap_config.h` and manually replace `"%SYSCONFDIR%"` by `"c:\\openldap\\sysconf"` as it used to be in php 5.4 and recompile php, the workaround doesn't work. It still looks for `C:\Apache24\%SYSCONFDIR%` dir literally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it will be fixed by php team in the next release.
See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65642